# Change background color scope

Tags: javascript, jquery

Var bgcolor, when outside the function changeBackground() dosn't work. I'm trying to understand scope in js. If the var is outside a function it should be global and vissible for the rest of code. When I bring the var bgcolor inside the function the program works. Why?

```js
var colors = ['#6aa085', '#a73e60', '#90fe50', '#231c12', '#e7043c', '#0b59b6', '#F66964', '#0f2224', "#4c0E32", "#B3BB99", "#a7a1A9", "#132857"]; // do not have to be inside the changeBackground function 
var bgcolor = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length); // must be inside the function 

function changeBackground() {
  $('#clock').animate({
    backgroundColor: colors[bgcolor],
  }, 2000);
}

window.setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Thank you for help.

Comment: You've not included the jQuery-ui library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `setTimeout` inside the complete callback of [`animate`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Using `setInterval` will not wait for the last animation to complete.

Also make sure you have added **JQuery** and **JQueryUI** library

**SNIPPET**

```js
var colors = ['#6aa085', '#a73e60', '#90fe50', '#231c12', '#e7043c', '#0b59b6', '#F66964', '#0f2224', "#4c0E32", "#B3BB99", "#a7a1A9", "#132857"]; // do not have to be inside the changeBackground function 



function changeBackground() {
  var bgcolor = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length); // must be inside the function 
  $('#clock').animate({
    backgroundColor: colors[bgcolor]
  }, 2000, function() {
    window.setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000); //Second animate after first completes
  });
}

window.setTimeout(changeBackground, 2000); //For first time
```

```css
#clock {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="clock"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I have JQuery and JQueryUI library icluded. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a scoping problem. The issue is because when you put the `bgColor` definition outside of the function it's only generated on load, not each time the interval calls `changeBackground()`. This means that the function sets the same colour on each call and appears to do nothing.

Also note that you cannot call `animate()` on the `backgroundColor` unless you've included jQueryUI in the page. Try this:

```js
var colors = ['#6aa085', '#a73e60', '#90fe50', '#231c12', '#e7043c', '#0b59b6', '#F66964', '#0f2224', "#4c0E32", "#B3BB99", "#a7a1A9", "#132857"];

function changeBackground() {
  var bgcolor = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  $('#clock').animate({
    backgroundColor: colors[bgcolor],
  }, 2000);
}

setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="clock">Clock</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var colors = ['#6aa085', '#a73e60', '#90fe50', '#231c12', '#e7043c', '#0b59b6', '#F66964', '#0f2224', "#4c0E32", "#B3BB99", "#a7a1A9", "#132857"]; // do not have to be inside the changeBackground function 


function changeBackground() {
  var bgcolor = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length); // must be inside the function 
  $('#clock').animate({
    backgroundColor: colors[bgcolor],
  }, 2000);
}

window.setInterval(changeBackground, 2000);
```

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="clock">Clock Area</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```